# Shortened link redirect

Tags: python, django, url

I'm making link shortener on django. I wonder how I can redirect shortened URL to it's original. 
For example I have a link `127.0.0.1:8000/ZY9J3y` and I need it to transfer me to `facebook.com`. The question is what should I add in my `url.py` in order to redirect links like this to their original??

Comment: With `path('<str:query>', my_view)` and then handle the `query` value in the view function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could configure a redirect directly in your urls.py:

**urls.py**

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = [
    path('ZY9J3y/', RedirectView.as_view(url='https://www.facebook.com'))
]
```

Or as suggested in the comments, you could use a view to figure out where to rediect to:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:query>', views.my_view)
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def my_view(request, query):
    if query == 'ZY9J3y':
        return redirect('https://www.facebook.com')
    raise Http404('Page does not exist')
```

Comment: I have a model that mathes generated short links and original links and I've managed to extract original urls and redirect them but ran into problem when if URL doesn't have an 'http://' before address it will redirect to unknown location localhost/shortenerapp/www.example.com. So youtube.com wont redirect me to youtube but "https:// youtube.com" will. How can I manage it to redirect directly by URL given and not to append URL to my site URL??

Comment: Yes without the "http://" the URL is considered to be relative and will get appended to the current path. Wherever your code retrieves the original link from a short link, it will need to manually check for the "http" prefix (scheme), and if not present prepend the "http" to the original link before returning it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a specific model for that:

**models.py**

```
class Redirection(models.Model):
    shortened = models.CharField("Shortened URL", max_length=50)
    url = models.URLField("Url", help_text='Your shortened URI will be computed')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Redirection"
        verbose_name_plural = "Redirections"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.shortened:
            self.shortened = self.computed_hash
        super(Redirection, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def computed_hash(self):
        return your_hashing_algo(self.url)
```

**urls.py**

```
from .views import redirect

urlpatterns = [
    path('(?P<surl>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/', redirect)
]
```

Finally, **views.py**

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
from django.shortcuts import (get_object_or_404, redirect)
from .models import Redirection

@cache_page(3600)
def redirect(request, surl):
    url = get_object_or_404(Redirection,shortened=surl)
    return redirect(url)
```

You can easily tweak that around to give model a lifespan, redirection counter (take care about the cache though!)